# How to add data to columns in SQLite?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite, python-3.5

I have rewritten my "death-row" program to add a few improvements and make it compatible with Python 3.

This is how it looks right now:

```
import sqlite3
import re
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string

URL=[]

conn = sqlite3.connect('prison.sqlite') 
conn.text_factory = str
cur = conn.cursor() 
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prison")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Prison (Execution text,Statement text, LastName text, Firstname text, TDCJNumber text, Age integer, Date text, Race text, County text)")
conn.commit()
url='http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html'
lines = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
prisondata = lines.read()
lines.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(prisondata,"html.parser")
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
url2 = url[:38]
for row in rows:
    td = row.find_all('td')
    try:
        Execution = str(td[0].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Execution) VALUES(?);", (str(Execution),))
        lastname= str(td[3].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Execution) VALUES(?);", (str(Execution),))
        firstname= str(td[4].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Firstname) VALUES(?);", (str(firstname),))
        tdcj= str(td[5].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (TDCJNumber) VALUES(?);", (str(tdcj),))
        Age= str(td[6].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Age) VALUES(?);", (str(Age),))
        Date= str(td[7].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Date) VALUES(?);", (str(Date),))
        Race= str(td[8].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Race) VALUES(?);", (str(Race),))
        County= str(td[9].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (County) VALUES(?);", (str(County),))
        links = row.find_all("a")
        link = links[1].get("href")
        LastStatementLink = url2 + link
        lines2 = urllib.request.urlopen(LastStatementLink)
        URL.append(LastStatementLink)

    except Exception:
        print ("An error has occured")
        continue

for U in URL:
    try:
        r = requests.get(U) 
        r.raise_for_status() 
        print ("URL OK"), U
        document = urllib.request.urlopen(U)
        html = document.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
        pattern = re.compile("Last Statement:") 
        Statement = soup.find(text=pattern).findNext('p').contents[0]
        print (Statement.encode("utf-8"))
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Statement) VALUES(?);", (str(Statement),))
        continue 
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print (err)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I have been trying for hours to get the correct data inserted in the SQLite)database, but I can't seem to get it right. For example:

```
 for row in rows:
        td = row.find_all('td')
        try:
            Execution = str(td[0].get_text())
            cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Execution) VALUES(?);", (str(Execution),))
```

The program has to find all the execution numbers in the table at stated website at position [0] and add it to the Database in the column "Execution" It has to do this for all the other parts of the data as well.

The problem is that python seems to create a new row every time it has to add a piece of data to the database. The program runs, but I have 4000 rows instead of around 540 in my SQLite-database.

I've tried multiple things, but I can't seem to get the data into the right columns, or end up with the correct amount of rows.

I've been thinking of a different approach: adding the pieces of data to lists and after that, add them to the database. This mean I would have 8 lists of data (one list for each execution number, firstname, lastname,...) But how do I add data from a list to SQLite?

Thanks!

Comment: Are You trying to update existing rows in the table where some condition is met, or to insert new row?

Comment: `INSERT` always adds new row - learn `SQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that python seems to create a new row every time it has
>   to add a piece of data to the database. The program runs, but I have
>   4000 rows instead of around 540 in my SQLite-database.

ahem, it's not python that's doing it but it's you. You have 8 insert statements where you should have one

```
 Execution = str(td[0].get_text())
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO prison (Execution,Firstname, ..., Race,) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", (str(Execution) , str(Firstname), ...))
```

ought to do it. Take care to count all the `?` make sure that all the column names are listed and you have added the values for all those columns.

Also, please note that it's customary that variables should start with lower case letters.

Comment: Thanks.e4c5  I was looking for a oneliner like that to insert everything at once.  Upvoted.

Comment: I know. Not enough rep :(

Comment: Aah, ic. I forgot indeed. Done!